# Iterate over children of inputs in parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="subdiv">
        <input value="1">
        <input value="2">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following code, and `onclick` event on click `div`. Now I want to iterate over all `input`s in this specific parent `div` (there are many).

So I wrote something like this:

```
$(this).parent().children('.subdiv input').not(':checked').length
```

It should output something like 1, or 2, depending of how many `input`s are unchecked. But it always shows 0.

Why is that so?

Also, how can I check/uncheck them all?

```
$(this).parent().find('.subdiv input').not(':checked').each(function() {
    // $(this) is undefined, or shows 0
});
```

Comment: input text do not have checked/unchecked property.

Comment: what is the `input` type?? if it is `text` why are checking for `not(":checked")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should declare those inputs as checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Then, on click of `.parent` element:

```
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
    // alert the number of checked checkboxes
    alert($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
});
```

In order to check a checkbox, use `prop()` function:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true); // sets input to checked state
```

In order to get the value of a checkbox:

```
var value = $('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
```

---

**DEMO**

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function() {
  var n = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  alert('There are ' + n + ' checked checkboxes');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="click"></div>
    <div class="subdiv">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" checked>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ASsuming all the inputs are checkbox or anything that can be checked
Use the below
1>No of inputs checked

```
$(this).parent().find('input:checked').length
```

1>No of inputs unchecked

```
$(this).parent().find('input').not(':checked').length
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `input`s will be `text`. And `checked` property does not work with text fields. It should be checkbox or radio. Try with -

```
<div class="subdiv">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input text do not have checked/unchecked property. You need to define type as checkbox for input elements:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2">
```

also you can narrown down the selector to get unchecked checkboxes to:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
 // $(this) is undefined, or shows 0
});
```